# What are the different pattern evaluation measures in data mining?

Tags: algorithm, data-mining, market-basket-analysis

In data mining, frequent itemset are found using  different algorithms like Apriori Algorithm , FP-Tree , etc. So are these the pattern evaluation methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try Association Rules (apriori for example), Collaborative Filtering (item-based or user-based) or even Clustering.

I don't know what you are trying to do, but if you have a data-set and you need to find the most frequent item-set you should try some of the above techniques.

If you're using R you should explore the arules package for association rules (for example).

Comment: Evaluating patterns is the same as finding association rules?

Comment: With data mining you use some methods to extract data patterns. So pattern evaluation that's when you identify interesting patterns that represent knowledge based on some measures.

Association rules is the discovery of the relationships among a set of items.

Answer (score 2):

Apriori algorithm and FP-tree algorithm is used to find frequent itemsets for the given transactional data. This would help in market basket analysis applications. For pattern evaluation, there are many components namely:

1. support,
2. confidence,
3. Lift,
4. Imbalance ratio, etc.

More details can be seen at the paper:

> Selecting the right interestingness measure for association patterns by Pang Ning Tan, Vipin Kumar, Jaideep Srivastava, KDD 2002.

- Refer URL: 
  http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.13.1494&rep=rep1&type=pdf